# OutOfMemoryError Matcher.replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, out-of-memory

In the following code, I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError

```
String resultStr = json.format(obj);
String regex = "null";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(resultStr);
resultStr = m.replaceAll("");
```

The stack trace is below:

```
at java/lang/StringBuffer.ensureCapacityImpl(StringBuffer.java:338(Compiled Code)) 
at java/lang/StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:204(Compiled Code)) 
at java/lang/StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:1031(Compiled Code)) 
at java/util/regex/Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:757(Compiled Code)) 
at java/util/regex/Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:824(Compiled Code))
```

I know replaceAll is expensive and can cause OOM. What is the most efficient way to avoid OOM in such a case?

I found there are similar questions on SO, but I'm not sure if any of them answers my question.

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for replacing a literal. My first advice would be to try replacing without `Pattern` / `Matcher` objects. Note that `String.replace` still uses regular expressions under the hood, but also ensures your search `String` is pattern-quoted, which might improve the memory footprint.

Comment: Hi Mena, in the code, the next line is regex = "\\[,\\]"; which is also replaced using Pattern/Matcher in similar way. For this I think I'll have to use Pattern/Matcher. What do you think?

Comment: well that seems to be a literal too, for `"[,]"`, since you're escaping the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives you could try:

1 - Increase the memory (using -Xmx in the command line)

2 - Break the String into smaller chunks, analyze the chunks, and do not forget to check if the ending of a chunk plus the beginning of the next contain the pattern.

This will help you to "tame" the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Incresing heap is one the of the solutions.
It would depend on the Java Version you are using.

1. If you are using Java6 or older versions, Strings are a part of PermGen Area and can be increased by XX:MaxPermSize=N
2. If you are using Java 7 or Java 8 , simply bumping  (-Xmx) should help.

If you still face issues post that, following link http://www.wikiconsole.com/analyzing-out-of-memory-situations/ should help

Comment: -Xms and -Xmx are already 2GB. Don't think it would be right to increase it further.

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: Java version is 1.6

Comment: Please try setting -XX:MaxPermSize=512M. It is a space for internalized strings in Java